# RTF Extract from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rtf, bcp

I have a column that I'm looking to extract but am having issues! The column is stored as type ntext and contains an RTF document so looks something like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deff0{\fonttbl  {\f0\fnil\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}  {\f1\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}  {\f2\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}  {\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}  {\stylesheet{\s0\itap0\nowidctlpar\f0\fs24 [Normal];}{\*\cs10\additive Default Paragraph Font;}}  {\*\generator TX_RTF32 15.0.530.502;}  \deftab1134\paperw11909\paperh16834\margl1138\margt1138\margr1138\margb1138\widowctrl\formshade\sectd  \headery720\footery720\pgwsxn11909\pghsxn16834\marglsxn1134\margtsxn1134\margrsxn1134\margbsxn1134\pard\itap0\nowidctlpar\plain\f1\fs20 Stephan Bos  28/11/2011 11:19:55\par\par Sold in guy. He likes him, feedback this afternoon.\par Will send him the CV and also our terms.\par Made him aware of our fees.\par }
```

But I'm looking to extract this back into (rtf or txt I don't really mind)
I've tried using BCP which has had success in extracting the documents but they end up exactly the same as the column but with spaces between each character rather than as I'd expect (example above would end up reading something like:

```
Stephan Bos  28/11/2011 11:19:55
Sold in guy. He likes him, feedback this afternoon.
Will send him the CV and also our terms.
Made him aware of our fees.
```

The BCP extract that I'm using (which is extracting) is as follows:

```
set nocount on;
Declare @sql varchar(1000);
declare @noteid int;
declare xx1 cursor for select nic.NotebookItemId from NotebookItemContent nic
inner join NotebookLinks nl on nl.NotebookItemId = nic.NotebookItemId
inner join NotebookItems ni on ni.NotebookItemId = nic.NotebookItemId
where nl.clientid = 1235074
AND ni.NotebookTypeId = 56;
open xx1;
fetch xx1 into @noteid;
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
set @sql = 'BCP "SELECT memo FROM Monarch_Pronet_ITOIL.dbo.notebookitemcontent where notebookitemid=' + cast(@noteid as varchar) + 
'" QUERYOUT \\bhamws475\docs\' + cast(@noteid as varchar) + '.rtf -T -f \\bhamws475\docs\bcp.fmt -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql
fetch xx1 into @noteid;
end;
close xx1;
deallocate xx1;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So the problem is that you don't have end lines in your output (just one big line)? I'd say they got lost somehow when you imported the data. If you execute a `select memo from . . . ` in the SQL query window setting the output to text do you see just one line or multiple ones?

Comment: I've taken a screenshot of the issue - http://i.imgur.com/kGMYO.png which should provide some insight!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which issue the screen-shot is showing. If you try to do as I suggested above do you see the multiple lines? (assuming that this is the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood now - the problem is that the RTF saved by BCP is not recognized as an RTF file by Word - it is opened as a plain text file.

This is due to the fact that the exported file is in Unicode (you see that by the fact that each character is followed by an empty space in the screen-shot).

The solution is to tell bcp to save not in Unicode - that I think can be done either with the `-c` switch or specifying the desired character set in the format file.